# How to control `Timer.publish()` when an App is in Background

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to make a timer app and I want to control `Timer.publish()` method when the app in the background.

In my App, I need to continue to work `Timer.publish()` to count up a number when the App in `active` and `background` So I made a setting like below:

- 1. Open the project file
- 2. Add the capability of the `Background Modes`
- 3. Check `Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture` as the image I attached

[image]

I want to continue to work `Timer.publish()` in the background only when I set a `running` as `timerStatus` , but in the case of my codes, even when I check `stoped`, `Timer.publish()` work in background.

How could I work `Timer.publish()` in the background only when I check `running` as `timerStatus`?
(I want to disappear `onRecieve` by `print` method when the app in the background and set `stoped` as `timerStatus` )

---

Here are the codes:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var timerStop = Timer()
    
    @State var appStatus: AppStatus = .active
    @State var timerStatus: TimerStatus = .running

    @State var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("RUN")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        timerStatus = .running
                    }
                Text("STOP")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        timerStatus = .stoped
                    }
            }
            Text(timerStatus == .running ? "running" : "stoped")
                .padding()
            Text(String(counter))
                .padding()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .active:
                appStatus = .active
            case .inactive:
                appStatus = .inactive
            case .background:
                appStatus = .background
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            print("onRecieve")
            if timerStatus == .running{
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

enum AppStatus {
    case active
    case inactive
    case background
}

enum TimerStatus {
    case running
    case stoped
}
```

TimerControlApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TimerControlApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App